# Jquery add class in a variable containig html string

Tags: jquery, class, object

I have this variable and i want to add a class to it.
I tryed this method, but this defenetly is not working

```
var someVar = '<i class="firstClass"></i>';// Html Markup to be used later.
    someVar.addClass('secondClass');
```

I need a different method to adding a new class to the html markup.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery's `addClass` method is only a method of a jQuery collection, and is used for adding a className to a DOM element.

Comment: You don't add classes to variable, you add classes to DOM elements. You variable needs to be a DOM element.

Comment: I've edited the content it did'yt show my full question

Comment: I know i don't have a way of actualy using addClass in this case, i'm just asking how i can do it in another way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use addClass on a HTML element so you need to set your variable to be a DOM element (e.g. `$('<i>')`):-

```
var someVar = $('<i>', {'class': 'firstClass'});
someVa.addClass('secondClass');
```

Comment: the <i> does not exist in the DOM it is just a html markup that will be used to append it to an object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i just made a newVar = $(someVar); and then changed it's class.

Answer (score 3):

When we need to get the html string from some DOM component we extracted from its parent, (eg: sortable helper), then we can convert that string to jquery object first.

example:

```
var thehtml = $(ui.helper).html();
    thehtml = $(thehtml); // convert to jquery object
    thehtml.addClass("yourClass"); // we can then assign new class

    ui.helper.replaceWith(thehtml); // do something you want with it
```

In your case

```
var someVar = '<i class="firstClass"></i>'; // Html Markup to be used later.
    someVar = $(someVar); // convert to jquery object
    someVar.addClass('secondClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var someVar = $('<i class="firstClass"></i>'); //embedded string in jquery object
someVar.addClass('secondClass');
```

Comment: the <i> does not exist in the DOM it is just a html markup that will be used to append it to an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in three ways:

1. You let your HTMl markup execute first so that you can get  as an DOM element and manipulate it.
2. The hard and ugly way, treat the markup as a string and manipulate the string using 'substring' and/or 'slice'.
3. Break up the markup and keep it in an array of strings, say 
   array[0] = i class=;
   array[1] = firstClass;
   array[2] = /i>;

   (i m new to stackoverflow and hence dnt knw how to write HTML in the answer, but i hope u got what i m tryin to explain)
   Then you can add as many classes as you want by simply concatinating the classname to a       array[1](array[1] += ' classname'). And when you actually want to use it, reform the whole markup by addind all the bits. It is still ugly, but you will atleast get what you want.

Comment: The thing is that the variable is basicali a option in a plugin i am making, that will pe set to accept only html. I made it to work by inspiring from one in the answer from the top.

Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: No problem. I saw the answers above and wanted to provide you with more alternatives if you wanted :)